# Can't connect to Amazon for cli use

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation

I'm trying to set up automated snapshots of my EBS volumes, for this I've set up the Amazon Cli tools, but when I go to try them out I get this error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

I do `telnet ec2.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com 443` and the same happens:

```
telnet: could not resolve ec2.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com/443: Name or service not known
```

This is the output of my `aws --version`:

```
aws-cli/1.7.4 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-29-generic
```

Comment: Try looking at the the hostname.  You should have something like ip-192-168-0-1.ec2.us-west2a.amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Region` setting for your CLI.

It would appear that the region has been incorrectly set to `us-west-2a`, which is an Availability Zone. The region name should be `us-west-2`.

This can be changed with the `aws configure` command.

Comment: Seems like this did it, let me finish checking and I'll let you know. Thank you!